# nextSibling returns null

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom, html

I am getting an error saying that "*this.nextSiblingElement.id is null*" when clearly I have set the IDs for the elements as they generate. Which I admit still could use some work. I was just curious what is the cause of the nextSiblingElement's ID being returned as null. I made sure that the previous element was generated before the drop-down menu and that the menu is placed before it with *previousChild.appendChild*.

I can edit the code down if necessary but I was not sure how much to show for the sake of it making sense. I am only showing the relevant functions as follows:

```
//helper function to add elements to the form
function createNewFormElement(inputForm, feildName, elementName, elementValue, elementType){

var inputString = String(feildName + ": <input name='" + elementName + "' type='" + elementType + "' /> ");
var newElement = document.createElement('div');

newElement.style.display = 'inline';

if (feildName == "Quantity" && containerType != "Box/Bag"){
    newElement.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}else{
    newElement.style.visibility = 'visible';
}
if (feildName == "Quantity"){
    newElement.id = "boxhide"+counter;
}else{
    newElement.id = 'dynamicInput';
}

newElement.innerHTML = inputString;

newElement.value = elementValue;
document.getElementById(inputForm.id).parentNode.appendChild(newElement);

return newElement;

}

//helper function to add dropdown
function createNewDropDown(inputForm, feildName, elementName){

    var dropDown, arValue;
    var newElement = document.createElement('div');

    newElement.id = 'dynamicInput';
    newElement.style.display = 'inline';

    dropDown = "<option value='" + containerType + "' selected>" + containerType + "</option>";


    for (i=0; i<conArray.length; i++){
        arValue = conArray[i];
        dropDown = dropDown + "<option value='" + arValue + "'>" + arValue + "</option>";
    }

    var inputString = String(feildName + ": <select onchange='switchMain(this.nextElementSibling.id);' name='" + elementName + "' id='" + elementName + "'>" + dropDown + "</select> ");

    newElement.innerHTML = inputString;
    document.getElementById(inputForm.id).parentNode.lastChild.previousSibling.appendChild(newElement);

    return newElement;
}
function getStyle(divName){

var temp = document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility;

return temp;
}

function switchMain(divName){

var e = document.getElementById("myContainers[]");
var strUser = e.options[e.selectedIndex].value;

if (strUser == "Box/Bag"){

    var current = getStyle(divName);

    //console.debug(current);

    document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility = "visible";
}else{
    document.getElementById(divName).style.visibility = "hidden";
}
}
```

Comment: Could you please post some relevant HTML as well to see how you're invoking those functions?

Comment: Where's the jQuery in this question?

Comment: Are you sure nextSibling is an element node or could it be a text node, perhaps a white space text node.

Comment: I can't find any usage of `nextSiblingElement` in the posted code. Could you please post only the relevant section? Btw, it should be [`nextElementSibling`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Element.nextElementSibling)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got an `inputString` like

```
"… <select onchange='switchMain(this.nextElementSibling.id);' …>…</select> "
```

Now, if you execute

```
newElement.innerHTML = inputString;
```

You can't expect that the select element has any sibling elements - it's the only (element) node inside the `newElement`:

```
<div …> … <select onchange='switchMain(this.nextElementSibling.id);' …>…</select> </div>
```

Therefore, `this.nextElementSibling` will be `null` and you get an exception when trying to get its `id` property.

> I made sure that the previous element was generated before the drop-down menu and that the menu is placed before it with previousChild.appendChild.

No, `appendChild` always inserts the new node in the end - regardless of the new parent's position in the DOM. If you want to insert an element in a special location, use [`insertBefore`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/Node.insertBefore).

Comment: Sorry, to those who wanted to see more of the code. I tried to keep it only to what was relevant and cut out the rest.

Bergi, thank you for your prompt reply. I guess I had been staring at the code too long to realize the mistake. I appreciate all the replies.